# Questions on Borsuk-Ulam theorem in 2d

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading [this](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) proof of Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $\Bbb S^2$ and have a couple of questions just to clear my understanding.

1. follows from the fact that an image of an equator under a particular map to $\Bbb S^1$ is not null-homotopic. Just for my understanding, does it mean that we proved the following result along the lines of the proof of BUT?

> There are no odd functions $g:\Bbb S^2\to \Bbb S^1$, that is those sending antipodal points to antipodal ones.

2. Since this is a course on algebraic topology, I thought about a purely topological formulation of BUT. That seems to imply that any map $f:X\to \Bbb R^2$ is guaranteed to assign the same value to two different points of $X$ if the latter is homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^2$. Am I correct? If this is the case, would BUT follow directly from that purely topological statement?
3. The proof also uses the fact that $\Bbb S^2$ has a trivial fundamental group, though I did not find any formal proof of that statement in the book. What is the easiest way to show this?

Answer (score 1):

1 It is a trivial consequence of Borsuk-Ulam. Such a map can be considered as a map $\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and so it would necessarily identify two antipodal points. A map identifying two antipodal points can't be odd.

2 Yes, you are correct, Borsuk-Ulam implies what you said. But I don't think that you can deduce BUT from that statement alone. That statement tells that any map $\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ identifies two points, but to go from that to the antipodal thing is the whole idea of BUT, and you would need to repeat Borsuk-Ulam's proof I'm afraid.

3 The fundamental group for the sphere may be calculated by Seifert-Van Kampen theorem. If you decompose $\mathbb{S}^2$ as the union of two open sets $U, V$, then $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2) = \pi_1(U)*_{\pi_1(U\cap V)} \pi_1(V)$, it is a "free amalgamated product". Choosing $U, V$ to be homeomorphic to the plane (for example $U$ is the sphere minus one pole, and $V$ the sphere minus the other pole), their fundamental groups are trivial and so it is their product.

Comment: Kudos on 1. Regarding 2: is it hard to show that given two distinct points on a topological sphere one can embed it in $\Bbb R^3$ so that they become antipodal? 3. By that time we have only showed that a convex subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ have trivial fundamental groups by constructing explicit homotopies, so I'd expect the proof for sphere to be a bit less technical.

Comment: About 2: I thought of that, but if you compose the map $\mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with an embedding, wouldn't that mean that *a different map* identifies antipodal points? That is, I think that BUT refers to a particular embedding of the sphere which you cannot change.

Comment: Van Kampen theorem is much more easier and less technical than it looks. If you understand fundamental groups from the point of view of coverings (absolutely essential thing), then a covering of the sphere is obviously the same as a pair of coverings of U, V which coincide on the intersection. Stating that obvious fact in the language of fund. groups you get Van Kampen theorem.

Comment: About 2: that's my question, and I am still not convinced there is no equivalence. About 3: I have no idea about van Kampen theorem, just it comes in the book after BUT and hence one should expect to show triviality of sphere's fundamental group without it.

Comment: Well, that's a problem of the book, and it should be solved there... In fact I think it's there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNpQq.png

Comment: And I don't see why someone would expect to deduce that a general map $\mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which is non injective must identify antipodal points (a very specific kind of non-injectiveness), without a non trivial proof. It is me who isn't convinced of what you state, and for a good reason.

Comment: Off-Topic, I don't understand why so many questions here ask about deducing such theorem from such another fact, instead of wanting the simplest, most clear and natural proof possible. Lots of people wanting to understand "Artin's", "Ahlfors'" or "Hatcher's" proofs, even when they are lame, just to preserve some "logical structure" of a book. I find that extremely boring. Books are just points of view and every one of them can be improved. Logic is boring. Understanding is fun.

Comment: To me, trying to understand reasoning (even though it is just one of the many possible ones) of a person who has some expertise on the subject I'm trying to learn is of value. Even if there is a better proof, that helps looking at the problem from different angles, which often helps in math.